# Fixed width, 100% height object in HTML

Tags: css, html, height

So, maybe I just suck at searching, but I'm having real trouble finding a method to do this, so here goes...

I have a webpage with a fixed image background (tiled, non scrolling).
I now want to have a colored div on top of that (700px wide, 100% height, centered) that I can then put more content within (doesn't necessarily have to be a div, I just want a colored area in the center.)

Here's an image of what I'm working towards: http://bit.ly/g5qgj0
The lightly colored area (on top of which lies everything else) is what I'm trying to achieve.

Thanks in advance, I'm still getting to know HTML/CSS and this has been driving me crazy XP

Comment: Second comment: Paste your code and what is wrong with it. We won't code your website for you.

Comment: And I wouldn't expect you to do any such thing...
I essentially don't have any code to paste, though, I'm just asking what the markup is to have an object with no content that can still be 100% height and fixed width.
(To clarify, the image I posted is just that - an image. No code. I am now working to implement what you see in real CSS and HTML.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
html, body{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    height:100%;
}
body{
    background:transparent url(...) repeat 0 0;
}
div{
    margin:0 auto;
    width:700px;
    height:100%;
    background:white;
}
```

### Check working example at http://jsfiddle.net/TGt4A/

Answer (score 1):

I think your most foolproof way to do this is going to involve Javascript/jQuery, which I did [in JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nycaY/). You might want to add a CSS `min-height` on that `#container` as a fallback if Javascript is disabled or whatever.

Comment: Hmm, interesting! Without implementing the Javascript you provided, I tried with just: `#container {
        margin: 0px auto; 
        width: 765px;
        min-height:100%;
        background-color:#e7eef3;
        padding:0;
}`
but the div is still only as high as the content within it.

Comment: Ah! Added `height=100%;` to `body` and `html` and now it all works just as I desired, sans Javascript even. Thanks a lot! :-)